# How to select the value of the dictionary by index and put it into the dataframe by key?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, object

I have a dictionary（dic）and a dataframe(df),a column in df is the keys in dic and a column is the index of the dic's value(Type:list), I want to add a column in df and it should matching key-value of dic and index.

input df:

```
    A   B   C
1   a   `   0
2   b   @   1
3   a   #   1
4   c   ￥  0
5   b   %   2
```

input dic:

```
{'a': ['apple', 'append'], 'b': ['boy', 'baby', 'bus'], 'c': ['cow', 'code'], 'd': ['dog', 'dislike']}
```

goal df:

```
    A   B   C   D
1   a   `   0  apple
2   b   @   1  baby
3   a   #   1  append
4   c   ￥  0  cow
5   b   %   2  bus
```

This is my current code:

```
df['D'] = dic[df['A']][df['C']]
```

Error:

```
TypeError: 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed
```

Please correct it, and the code should be executed as efficiently as possible.

Answer (score 3):

You could define a list of tuples from both columns in the dataframe, and use each value to index the input dictionary and inner lists:

```
d_ = tuple(zip(df['A'], df['C']))
# (('a', 0), ('b', 1), ('a', 1), ('c', 0), ('b', 2))
df['D'] = [d[a][c] for a,c in d_]

   A  B  C       D
1  a  `  0   apple
2  b  @  1    baby
3  a  #  1  append
4  c  ￥  0     cow
5  b  %  2     bus
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `merge` and convert your input dictionary to a dataframe:

```
dd = {'a': ['apple', 'append'], 
      'b': ['boy', 'baby', 'bus'], 
      'c': ['cow', 'code'], 
      'd': ['dog', 'dislike']}
df_dd = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dd, orient='index')

df.merge(df_dd.stack().rename('D').reset_index(), 
          left_on=['A', 'C'], 
          right_on=['level_0','level_1'])[['A','B','C','D']]
```

Output:

```
   A  B  C       D
0  a  `  0   apple
1  b  @  1    baby
2  a  #  1  append
3  c  ￥  0     cow
4  b  %  2     bus
```

Comment: In two weeks I will travel across the Pacific to Texas，hhhhhh

Comment: @王彦琛 Awesome.  Which city.

Answer (score 1):

I would use [`map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) and [`lookup`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.lookup.html) (considering the dictionary name is `d` you can do):

```
df['D']=pd.DataFrame(df.A.map(d).values.tolist(),
                   index=df.index).lookup(df.C.index,df.C.values)
print(df)
```

---

```
   A  B  C       D
1  a  `  0   apple
2  b  @  1    baby
3  a  #  1  append
4  c  ￥  0     cow
5  b  %  2     bus
```